# How to automatically rollback a transaction in psql's interactive mode?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, psql

Let us assume the following contents of the file `erroneous-query.sql`:

```sql
BEGIN;
SELECT 1/0;
COMMIT;
```

When I say `\i erroneous-query.sql` in psql's interactive mode, I get this:

```
BEGIN
psql:erroneous-query.sql:2: ERROR:  division by zero
```

but I need to say `ROLLBACK;` manually - otherwise, the transaction is hanging (and blocking everything else).

How can I configure psql to rollback this transaction automatically for me?  I tried `\set ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK off`, but to no avail.

Comment: You need `\set ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK on`  (**on**, not off)

Comment: Not really. The manual says: "When set to on, if a statement in a transaction block generates an error, the error is ignored and the transaction continues", and that's not what I'm after.

Comment: Read the whole description: "*The error rollback mode works by issuing an implicit SAVEPOINT for you, just before each command that is in a transaction block, and then rolling back to the savepoint if the command fails*" If it's on, you can continue to run queries without having to issue a manual rollback. The statement that caused the error is rolled back automatically.

Comment: OK, but I'd like to roll back the whole transaction.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  When I do this, it sees the "COMMIT" inside the errored-out transaction and interprets it as a ROLLBACK.  There is no open transaction afteward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make `psql` issue a `ROLLBACK` automatically.

But an aborted transaction (a transaction that had an error and has no savepoints) will release all locks immediately, so it will never block anybody else.

The remaining statements in the transaction will be done very quickly, each of them will cause

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Doing what you propose would actually be very dangerous: that way part of a transaction (the statements after the error) would be executed in different transactions, and the atomicity of the whole transaction would be lost.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about ignoring the rest of the statements in the transaction, of course.